# Neo4j - Loop through relationships with conditions and variables in loop

Tags: neo4j

How is it possible to loop through relationships in a specific order (e.g.: "created" property) and taking the single properties of the relationships into consideration.

I prepared one example:
Imagine we have 3 users (nodes) who each collect (relationship) 40kg Apples with a created-timestamp. On the other hand, we have a basket (node) with can take 100kg. How is it possible to loop through all 3 relationships and fill the basket with exactly 100kg? The goal would be to take the full 40kg of the two oldest-created-relationships and to take only 20kg from the youngest-relationship. This scenario needs to deal with the single relationships-properties within the loop.

The result could be that we change/add properties of the existing COLLECTS-relationship or add new relationships between the Basket and the User.

Thank you

The schema of the example looks like this:
[image]

In Neo4j the relationships/nodes could be created by this:

```
create 
(_0:`Basket`  {`size`:100}),
(_1:`User`  {`name`:"Franc"}),
(_6:`User`  {`name`:"Peter"}),
(_34:`User`  {`name`:"Betty"}),
(_54:`Fruit` ),
(_1)-[:`COLLECTS` {`created`:"20221206212715",`kilos`:40,`type`:"Apples"}]->(_54),
(_6)-[:`COLLECTS` {`created`:"20221206212417",`kilos`:40,`type`:"Apples"}]->(_54),
(_34)-[:`COLLECTS` {`created`:"20221206212547",`kilos`:40,`type`:"Apples"}]->(_54)
```